# Creating a leaderboard w/ variables [python]

Tags: python, variables

I've been required to read from a file (firesideResults.txt)
must calculate the points totals for each player from the firesideResults.txt file
and display them in a leader board.
• It must award three points per win.
• It must only include players in the leader board who have won at least one match.
• It must display the details in this format:

This is my current code:

```
def option_C():

print("-Fixtures Leaderboard-")

print('\nPlayer Nickname\t\tMatches Played\t\tMatches Won\t\tMatches Lost\t\tPoints')

print('-' * 65)

for line in open('firesideResults.txt'):

    line = line.strip()

    nickname,played,won,lost = line.split(",")

    if int (won) >0:

        points = int(won)*3

        print(nickname+'\t'+played+'\t\t'+won+'\t\t'+lost+'\t\t'+str(points)
```

But I can't seem to display them in a leaderboard with highest to lowest.

TXT FILE

Leeroy,19,7,12

Jenkins,19,8,11

Tyler,19,0,19

Napoleon Wilson,19,7,12

Big Boss,19,7,12

Game Dude,19,5,14

Macho Man,19,3,16

Space Pirate,19,6,13

Billy Casper,19,7,12 O

tacon,19,7,12

Big Brother,19,7,12

Ingsoc,19,5,14

Ripley,19,5,14

M’lady,19,4,15

Einstein100,19,8,11

Dennis,19,5,14

Esports,19,8,11

RNGesus,19,7,12

Kes,19,9,10

Magnitude,19,6,13

Comment: Currently you are just reading each line from file and printing it, There is not sorting code so its not getting sorted.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but could you tell me how to do that, i'm really stuck :/

Comment: How do you want to sort the list? Highest Matches? Highest wins? Highest loss?

Comment: Highest points 'points = int(won)*3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reading and printing all in one loop,

First read it into a list

Then use Python's `sorted` function, Read about sorted here [Python Sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
print("-Fixtures Leaderboard-")

print('\nPlayer Nickname\t\tMatches Played\t\tMatches Won\t\tMatches Lost\t\tPoints')

print('-' * 65)

scores = []
for line in open('firesideResults.txt'):
    line = line.strip()
    nickname,played,won,lost = line.split(",")
    if int (won) >0:
        points = int(won)*3
    else: 
        points = 0
    scores.append((nickname, played, won, lost, points))

sorted_scores = sorted(scores, key= lambda x: x[4], reverse=True)
for score in sorted_scores:
    print('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' % score)
```

Lambda is kind of a function without name, Read about it here [Lambdas](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk)

Notice the `lambda x: x[4]` in the sorted_scores line, This says that sort the list based on the 4th column, You can sort by other columns as well by changing that `4`

All the best

Comment: I think its fine, but im on a mac and line.split doesnt seem to be working.     nickname,played,won,lost = line.split(",")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the results right away, consider storing each line in a Player class, then adding it to a list of players. After iterating through the file, you can easily sort the list by score with the key parameter in sorted(). For example, if your list of players is called "player_list" and the player class has the attribute "points," your sorting code might look something like

```
player_list = sorted(player_list, key = lambda player: player.points)
```

At which point you can easily iterate through the list and print each player's stats.

Comment: what is lambda, i am quite a 'noob' with python xD

Comment: basically a one-line function. In this case it is used to declare a function that converts a Player object into an integer that can be used for sorting.